# netctl "no connection found"

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux

I've just installed Arch Linux.

I'm trying to connect to my local network but its not working.

Here is my data:

lspci -v

```
...
3:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f2104000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f2100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
...
```

ip link show enp3s0

```
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

netctl profile:

```
Interface=enp3s0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('192.168.1.20/24')
Gateway='192.168.1.1'
DNS=('8.8.8.8' '8.8.4.4')
```

And I get this error:

```
--
-- Unit netctl@default_profile.service has begun starting up.
Jan 11 21:48:58 main network[496]: Starting network profile 'default_profile'...
Jan 11 21:48:58 main kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Jan 11 21:48:58 main kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Jan 11 21:48:58 main kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
Jan 11 21:49:03 main network[496]: No connection found on interface 'enp3s0' (timeout)
Jan 11 21:49:03 main network[496]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'default_profile'
Jan 11 21:49:03 main systemd[1]: netctl@default_profile.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 11 21:49:03 main systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile default_profile.
-- Subject: Unit netctl@default_profile.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit netctl@default_profile.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jan 11 21:49:03 main systemd[1]: netctl@default_profile.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 11 21:49:03 main systemd[1]: netctl@default_profile.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 11 21:49:03 main systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
-- Subject: Unit network.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit network.target has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

If I try to connect using:

```
dhcpcp enp3s0
```

it works fine, but I want to connect using netctl. How can I do it?

Comment: "no carrier" means the interface isn't connected/the cable is shot/the switch is off or broken/...

Comment: Nop, everything is connected. When I run "dhcpcd" it connects to the network fine. The problem is using "netctl" to connect it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have `dhcpcd` running? If so, it will interfere with `netctl`. You can check with `systemctl list-units | grep dhcpcd`.

Comment: It's not running, it's disabled and stopped.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, i'm going to see if I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem, and found this question while looking for a solution.

Turns out I found a solution after all though so I'm gonna post it here. You need to add this option to your netctl profile:

```
SkipNoCarrier=yes
```

What seems to be happening is that the error "**No connection found on interface 'enp3s0' (timeout)**" indicates that **netctl** is for whatever reason (lol) failing to detect the connection to your router, it's basically saying "No connection detected, is your cable plugged in?"

But the cable in fact is connected as turning on your connection via **dhcpcd** would suggest, so this can only be a bug within **netctl**.

The solution is to (with the option I described above) tell **netctl** to ignore whether or not the device is connected to anything, and just enable the interface (set the link up) and try to connect anyways.

I'm not sure how I feel about this, it makes me feel kinda like maybe netctl isn't so good and I shouldn't be using it anyways, but hey, this works, and until it doesn't anymore, guess I'll stick with it.

Comment: Also for reference, I was not on an Asus board, I was on an MSI board. MSI, **MSI H81M-E33** to be exact, in case anyone wants to try to replicate, troubleshoot and fix this bug. What we do have in common is the r8169 kernel driver that the Realtek ethernet card uses (even if said ethernet card may not be the exact same make, and are on different subsystems (e.g. asustek for him, MSI for me)